# Trying to insert content before 2nd h2 tag

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to insert a shortcode [toc] but i am doing something wrong, because doesnt work.

- I tried `$new_content .= do_shortcode ('[toc]');` WHITE page
- I tried `$new_content .= '[toc]';` WHITE page
- If i put `$new_content .= '<span>gg</span>';` IT WORKS.

The plugin is easy table of contents

I am using this code in funstions.php

```
function insert_ad_in_content($content)
{
    if ((!is_singular('post')) || (strpos($content, '<h2') === FALSE) ) {  return $content; }

    $ChapterCount = 2; // Enter the chapter number, which you'd like an add in front of

    $content = explode("<h2", $content);

    $new_content = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
        if ($i == $ChapterCount) {
            $new_content .= do_shortcode('[toc]');
        }

        if($i>0) {
          $new_content.= "<h2".$content[$i];
        } else {
          $new_content.= $content[$i];
        }
    }

    return $new_content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'insert_ad_in_content');
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Is `special` not outputting? Did you create the shortcode? Does the shortcode work if you put it in the WYSIWYG?

Comment: Yeah! It works if i use it in  WYSIWYG, but with this code the whole post appears in blank.

Comment: Maybe is because its a table of content? toc?